# Finding nearest line and its x,y location

Tags: math, geometry, line, point

Suppose that I have the following graph. I know A,B,C,D,E location(x,y). My problem is how to find which line is the nearest with point E. And also I want to draw a new line (blue color) between point and the nearest line. How can I found the (x,y) so that I can draw the line?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean line or line segment ? These are two different problems.

Comment: There are many web sites, including Wikipedia, that discuss how to find the distance from a point to a line and/or the point on a line closest to another point. What research have you done so far on this problem, and just where are you stuck? Have you attempted any code? Could you show us your code attempt?

Comment: If you can afford to compute the distances from the point to all segments, use the approach by MBo. If you need to answer the query for numerous points, you can preprocess the segments and generate their Voronoi diagram, then use a point location procedure. This is much more complicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make projection of point E onto line AB, determine whether that projection lies in the range of AB segment and find length of perpendicular to projection point. Same for CD segment.

To find projection point, get direction vector of AB  and AE

```
AB = (B - A)
AE = (E - A)
```

and find parameter using scalar product of

```
 t = (AB * AE) / (AB * AB)
```

if t lies out of rnage 0..1, then the closest point of segment is one of the ends. Otherwise find propjection point and length of projection

```
P = A + AB * t
Len = length(E - P)
```